# Call part of a replaced list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, algebraic-manipulation

I have what I believe to be a very simple problem. I want to use an equation which depends on the values inside a list, but to be able to evaluate that equation with different lists. So:

```
T = Sum[A + b[[i]], {i, 10}];
```

I then want to be able to evaluate this with different sets of values for `A` and the list `b`. But if I try

```
Vals1 = {A-> 1, b-> Table[j^2,{j,10}]};
T//.Vals1
```

I get the correct answer, but I also get the error code `"Part specification b[[1]] is longer than depth of object."`

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Define `T` with arguments and require `b` to be a `List`

```
T[A_, b_List] := Sum[A + b[[i]], {i, 10}];

Vals1 = {A -> 1, b -> Table[j^2, {j, 10}]};

T[A, b] /. Vals1

(* 395 *)

T[1, Range[10]^2]

(* 395 *)
```

Comment: This is a great solution and solves the problem. However, I'm still perplexed - what was wrong in the original question?

Comment: The primary problem was that you used `Set` (`=`) rather than `SetDelayed` (`:=`) when defining `T`. Since the RHS was immediately evaluated, `b` had no parts. Then `T //. Vals1` evaluated `T` before the replacements were made, so again `b` had no parts. Using explicit arguments with `b_List` precluded `T[A, b]` from evaluating until after the replacements thereby ensuring that `b` had parts.